# Biblatex bibliography: No numbers affixed to formatted entries

Tags: biblatex

I want to remove the numeric labels in front the bibliography entries ([1] [2] or (1) (2)) so that I only have my bibitem (without the numbering). How can I do that?

This is what I'm using:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,citestyle=authoryear,
      bibstyle=chem-biochem,citetracker=true,
      maxcitenames=2,giveninits=false,
      maxbibnames=99,isbn=false,url=false,
      urldate=comp,natbib=true]{biblatex} 
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{} 
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
   andothers = {\em et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}
}
```

It's a combination of styles (but that results in exactly what I want) minus of course the bib item labels which I still want removed

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[german]{babel} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{makeidx} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry} 

\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,citestyle=authoryear,
      bibstyle=chem-biochem,citetracker=true,
      maxcitenames=2,giveninits=false,
      maxbibnames=99,isbn=false,url=false,
      urldate=comp,natbib=true]{biblatex} 
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{} 
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
   andothers = {\em et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}
}
\addbibresource{LitDaten.bib} 
\usepackage{filecontents}   
\begin{filecontents}{LitDaten.bib} 
@BOOK{Rost2005, 
AUTHOR = {Rost, Detlef H.}, 
YEAR = {2005}, 
TITLE = {Interpretation und Bewertung pädagogisch-psychologischer Studien -         
}, 
   EDITION = {2. überarb. u. erw. A.}, 
   ISBN = {978-3-825-28306-3}, 
   PUBLISHER = {Beltz}, 
   ADDRESS = {Langensalza}, 
} 
\end{filecontents} 
\begin{filecontents}{Datatop.bib} 
    @BOOK{Jeff2021, 
    AUTHOR = {Jeff, Jeff H.}, 
    YEAR = {1984}, 
    TITLE = {something important but unseen        
    }, 
       EDITION = {1283}, 
       ISBN = {123-4-567-78999-0}, 
       PUBLISHER = {penugin}, 
       ADDRESS = {seatle}, 
    } 
    \end{filecontents}

\begin{document} 

asdfasdf asd \cite{Rost2005} fasdf asdf \cite{Jeff2021} asdf asdf 

\printbibliography[title=Bibliography] 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you could choose a pair of `bibstyle` and `citestlye` which would fit better. But apparently, you already thought of it and still chose `bibstyle=chem-biochem`. In this case, we can "borrow" the `bibenvironment` from the `authoryear` bibstyle, which does not use the labels, with:

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
```

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,citestyle=authoryear,
      bibstyle=chem-biochem,citetracker=true,
      maxcitenames=2,giveninits=false,
      maxbibnames=99,isbn=false,url=false,
      urldate=comp,natbib=true]{biblatex} 
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
   andothers = {\em et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}
}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it worked like a charm ! thank you very much ! eventhou i am confused (i found something similar tried it and it never worked but now it does.....latex eh ? :)

Comment: new issue, for some reason now the fields month, city and country are not showing up for all my bib items

Comment: @PeterFesterling Well, that could hardly be related to the `bibenvironment` and is very likely related to `bibstyle=chem-biochem`. I suggest you ask a new question, providing a MWE and including some of the affected entries. Still, you might reconsider the choice of `chem-biochem` and go for `authoryear`, making the adaptations that you need.

Comment: i have to chose chem-biochem, simply because if i use author year (by its own) the bib style is messed up, i need for example Jones,T.,Peters,P.,...... (which i can get using chem-biochem) if i dont use it and rely on authoryear alone it gives me Jones,T.,P.,Peters,...... which is wrong for my citation needs

Comment: mew is still the same as the one provided above just add month, city and country (im using a numeric value for month btw)

Comment: @PeterFesterling, even if the MWE is the same (but do the shown entries show the problem?), if it's another issue, it deserves another question. This is a QAs site, and things tend to be less clear if several issues are bundled. And the question is here not just for you, but for others that might face the same or a similar problem. You've asked a question, I've provided an answer which I hope is useful to you. If you have another issue, ask a new question.